# How can I remove listeners from an object in Seesaw if I haven't kept the return function?

Tags: clojure, seesaw

To add a listener to a UI element in Seesaw you do this:

```
(listen ui-element :action (fn [_] (...)))
```

`listen` attaches a listener that calls the provided function when `:action` is triggered on `ui-element1. It also *returns* a function. If you execute that function it removes the listener that was added with the original call.

I've been prototyping UIs in the REPL using Seesaw, and I haven't kept the return values from `listen`.

**If I don't have the returned function, how can I remove listeners?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually remove listeners in the following crude way:

```
user=> (def b (button :text "HI"))
user=> (listen b :action #(alert % "HI!"))
user=> (-> (frame :content b) pack! show!)
; click the button, see the alert
; manually remove listeners
user=> (doseq [l (.getActionListeners b)] (.removeActionListener b l))
; click the button, nothing happens
```

You could put this in a helper function and use it whenever. Having this built-in somehow to `seesaw.event` or `seesaw.dev` would also be nice. Patches welcomed. :)

Comment: This works on a `button`, but it doesn’t work on a `listbox` that has a listener on the `:selection` event, as in the [Seesaw REPL Tutorial](https://gist.github.com/daveray/1441520#file-seesaw-repl-tutorial-clj-L195-L244). In that case, I just recreated the listbox with the same options and then set the contents of the frame to the new listbox.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that if you don't have that function reference. What you can do is use `*1` special vara in REPL, which basically stores the result of last executed expression, to remove the handlers from the REPL.

Comment: Yep, though in this case I'd already moved too far forward in the REPL and so lost those references too.